# How to debug "IndexError: list index out of range"?

Tags: python

I'm getting "IndexError: list index out of range" from

```
buffer.append(data[data_index])
```

My code is as below:

```
data_index = 0
def generate_batch(batch_size, num_skips, skip_window):
  global data_index
  assert batch_size % num_skips == 0
  assert num_skips <= 2 * skip_window
  batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size), dtype=np.int32)
  labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)
  span = 2 * skip_window + 1  # [ skip_window target skip_window ]
  buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=span)
  for _ in range(span):
    buffer.append(data[data_index])
    data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is raised when the index (in this case `data_index`) is greater than or equal to the length of the list (in this case `data`). There are a lot of potential reasons that this problem could arise (such as corrupt input data), but the best starting point would be to print out the values of `len(data)` and `data_index` when the error is raised.